# Converting Morse Code to English Dictionary Words

Tags: java, recursion, morse-code

Am trying to solve a problem that given a string of morse code characters find the meaningful words in dictionary

For example

This input string "..-.----..-.-...---..-.--" should translate to "fox lazy", there can be multiple other translations possible, but this is one possible solution since these 2 words are present in the English dictionary.

I wrote 2 functions, TranslateMorse and SegmentString.
SegmentString splits an English string and finds all the meaningful words in the dictionary. For example if input is "foxlazy", the function can find "fox" and "lazy" are 2 meaningful words present in the dictionary.

The TranslateMorse should actually translate the morse code input "..-.----..-.-...---..-.--" to "foxlazy" so that SegmentString gives the resultant output, but the tricky part is MorseCode translation is not straight forward and it gives me many translations.

How do I solve this problem?

```
import java.util.*;

public class MorseCode {
    String TranslateMorse(String input, Map<String, String> morse) {
        // "-.-..-.--..--...-....---"
        if (morse.containsKey(input))
            return morse.get(input);
        int len = input.length();
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            String prefix = input.substring(0, i);
            if (morse.containsKey(prefix)) {
                String suffix = input.substring(i, len);
                String segSuffix = SegmentString(suffix, morse);
                if (segSuffix != null) {
                    return morse.get(prefix) + segSuffix;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    String SegmentString(String input, Set<String> dict) {
        if (dict.contains(input))
            return input;
        int len = input.length();
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            String prefix = input.substring(0, i);
            if (dict.contains(prefix)) {
                String suffix = input.substring(i, len);
                String segSuffix = SegmentString(suffix, dict);
                if (segSuffix != null) {
                    return prefix + " " + segSuffix;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Driver method
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String, String> morse = new HashMap<>();
        morse.put(".-", "a");
        morse.put("-...", "b");
        morse.put("-.-.", "c");
        morse.put("-..", "d");
        morse.put(".", "e");
        morse.put("..-.", "f");
        morse.put("--.-", "g");
        morse.put("....", "h");
        morse.put("..", "i");
        morse.put(".---", "j");
        morse.put("-.-", "k");
        morse.put(".-..", "l");
        morse.put("--", "m");
        morse.put("-.", "n");
        morse.put("---", "o");
        morse.put(".--.", "p");
        morse.put("--.-", "q");
        morse.put(".-.", "r");
        morse.put("...", "s");
        morse.put("-", "t");
        morse.put("..-", "u");
        morse.put("...-", "v");
        morse.put(".--", "w");
        morse.put("-..-", "x");
        morse.put("-.--", "y");
        morse.put("--..", "z");

        Set<String> dict = new HashSet<>();
        dict.add("apple");
        dict.add("honey");
        dict.add("fox");
        dict.add("quick");
        dict.add("jumped");
        dict.add("bill");
        dict.add("jam");
        dict.add("holy");
        dict.add("mega");
        dict.add("lazy");
        // fox lazy
        String input = "..-.----..-.-...---..-.--";
        MorseCode m = new MorseCode();
        String alpha = m.TranslateMorse(input, morse);
        System.out.println(alpha);
        System.out.println(m.SegmentString(alpha, dict));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the point of this problem is that there are no letter, nor word, separators (spaces) in the stream of morse clicks and that's part of the analysis.  The key problems I see with your code are:

- You assume you're going to get back a single answer, reflected in your choice of data types, when in fact you are going to get back multiple answers that need to be filtered.
- Your `TranslateMorse()` method calls `SegmentString()` when it should be calling itself recursively!

Below is my rework of your code that addresses these two problems:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MorseCode {

    List<String> TranslateMorse(String input, Map<String, String> dictionary) {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (dictionary.containsKey(input)) {
            strings.add(dictionary.get(input));
        }

        int length = input.length();

        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            String prefix = input.substring(0, i);

            if (dictionary.containsKey(prefix)) {
                String suffix = input.substring(i, length);
                List<String> translations = TranslateMorse(suffix, dictionary);

                if (! translations.isEmpty()) {
                    String letter = dictionary.get(prefix);

                    for (String translation : translations) {
                        strings.add(letter + translation);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return strings;
    }

    List<String> SegmentString(String input, Set<String> wordList) {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (wordList.contains(input))
            strings.add(input);

        int length = input.length();

        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            String prefix = input.substring(0, i);

            if (wordList.contains(prefix)) {
                String suffix = input.substring(i, length);
                List<String> expansions = SegmentString(suffix, wordList);

                if (! expansions.isEmpty()) {
                    for (String expansion : expansions) {
                        strings.add(prefix + " " + expansion);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return strings;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String, String> morse = new HashMap<>();

        morse.put(".-", "a");
        morse.put("-...", "b");
        morse.put("-.-.", "c");
        morse.put("-..", "d");
        morse.put(".", "e");
        morse.put("..-.", "f");
        morse.put("--.-", "g");
        morse.put("....", "h");
        morse.put("..", "i");
        morse.put(".---", "j");
        morse.put("-.-", "k");
        morse.put(".-..", "l");
        morse.put("--", "m");
        morse.put("-.", "n");
        morse.put("---", "o");
        morse.put(".--.", "p");
        morse.put("--.-", "q");
        morse.put(".-.", "r");
        morse.put("...", "s");
        morse.put("-", "t");
        morse.put("..-", "u");
        morse.put("...-", "v");
        morse.put(".--", "w");
        morse.put("-..-", "x");
        morse.put("-.--", "y");
        morse.put("--..", "z");

        Set<String> english = new HashSet<>();

        english.add("apple");
        english.add("honey");
        english.add("fox");
        english.add("quick");
        english.add("jumped");
        english.add("bill");
        english.add("jam");
        english.add("holy");
        english.add("mega");
        english.add("lazy");

        String input = "..-.----..-.-...---..-.--"; // fox lazy
        MorseCode decoder = new MorseCode();
        List<String> decodings = decoder.TranslateMorse(input, morse);

        for (String decoding : decodings) {
            List<String> phrases = decoder.SegmentString(decoding, english);

            for (String phrase : phrases) {
                System.out.println(input + " -> " + decoding + " -> " + phrase);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
> java MorseCode
..-.----..-.-...---..-.-- -> foxlazy -> fox lazy
>
```

This is not a quick program--it takes about 10 seconds in this example as it has to filter through all the possible interpretations of the dits and dahs into Morse code symbols, and then filter those through the English word list.

Comment: Thank you very much @cdlane 
I noticed the bug that I call SegmentString in Translate Morse, but even after fixing that the permutations and combinations were way too high especially there being no delimiter (which is not the ideal case, even in the real world there was always a character delimiter for Morse Codes. Word delimiter is optional).

Thanks again for the corrected code. Like you mentioned it takes a long time. I believe the complexity of the functions is exponential.